# Is it possible to have a Live Caller ID application with Nativescript?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

Does anyone have any idea how can I implement a Live Caller ID?

For example, if I create an application that has a contact (John Snow: +00001) and the user doesn't have that contact in the native contacts list, I would like to add the feature when the user receives a call from +00001, to show John Snow instead.

Inspiration : [TrueCaller](https://www.truecaller.com/)

Comment: On iOS you need to create a CallKit extension and have it register all of the names/numbers. I don't know if it possible to create a CallKit extension in NativeScript.

Comment: As of now writing an iOS extension is not very much straight forward but still possible, here is a POC - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ios-imessages There is a open feature request for making this process easy - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3965

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. Basically you are going to use a broadcast receiver that will listen for a new incoming call, there you get the number and launch your activity / widget like TrueCaller.

Comment: Thanks. 
Do you have any doc links where I can learn how to do that, please?

Comment: Check this thread - https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/can-anyone-share-sample-example-for-sms-receiver/3616

Comment: Above is just an example for writing broad cast receivers in NativeScript, you will have to do something similar for listing to incoming calls.